# General error: could not call class constructor'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just trying to make operation which looks pretty simple but getting a strange error

> Uncaught exception: 'PDOException'
>
> Message: 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: could not call class constructor'
>
> Stack trace:
>
> ```
> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\Core\Model.php(48): PDOStatement->fetch()
> 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\App\Controllers\Admin\Rooms.php(188): Core\Model::findById('98')***
> 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\Core\Router.php(78): App\Controllers\Admin\Rooms::deletePhoto()
> 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\public\index.php(62): Core\Router->dispatch('admin/rooms/del...')
> 4 {main}**
> ```
>
> Thrown in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\Core\Model.php' on line 48

This is the function which causes this error.

```
 public static function findById($id){

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . static::$db_table . ' WHERE id = :id';
        $db = static::getDB();
        $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());

        $statement->execute();

        return $statement->fetch();
    }
```

I already checked composer.json psr-4 section and it looks like all directories with my classes are there. 
So why can I get this error?

And here is the whole class with that method

```
namespace Core;

use PDO;
use App\Config;
abstract class Model {


protected static function getDB()
{
    static $db = null;

    if ($db === null) {

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' .
            Config::DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
        $db = new PDO($dsn, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);

        // Throw an exception when an error occurs
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }
    return $db;
}

// finds everything by ID (photo, user, booking)
public static function findById($id){

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . static::$db_table . ' WHERE id = :id';
    $db = static::getDB();
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\App\Models\Admin\Photo');

    $statement->execute();

    return $statement->fetch();
}

// this method deletes via id
public static function delete($id){

    $sql = 'DELETE FROM ' . static::$db_table . ' WHERE ' . static::$column .  ' = :id';

    $db = static::getDB();
    $statament = $db->prepare($sql);

    $statament->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    return $statament->execute();
}

// returns everything from selected database table
public static function findAll(){

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . static::$db_table;

    $db  = static::getDB();
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());

    $stm->execute();

    return $stm->fetchAll();
}



}
```

And here my Photo class: `
    namespace App\Models\Admin;

```
use PDO;
use \App\Config;


class Photo extends \Core\Model {

public $errors_on_upload = [];                          // array for saving error messages
public static $db_table = 'photos';                     // database table
public static $column = 'id';
protected static $upload_derictory = 'public\uploads\pictures\rooms'; // path to uploaded pictures
protected static $path = '/uploads/pictures/rooms';
protected static $path_to_unlink = 'uploads/pictures/rooms/';
public $upload_errors_array = array(


    UPLOAD_ERR_OK            => "There is no errors",
    UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE      => "The uploaded file exceeds max size",
    UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE     => "The uploaded file exceeds max size of form post request",
    UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL       => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE       => "No file was uploaed",
    UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR    => "Missing the temporary folder",
    UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE    => "Failed to write to disk",
    UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION     => "A php extension stopped the file upload",

);


// supplied with $_FILES and input name of multiply input file
public function __construct($picture) {

        // here we creates properties and their values out of keys and values
        foreach($picture as $key => $value){
            $this->$key = $value;
            //echo $key;
        }

}

// creates a easy-readable array of properties and their values out of multiply-files array from form
// must be supplied with argument in format $_FILES['input_name']
public static function reArrayFiles($file_post) {

    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++){
        foreach ($file_keys as $key){
            $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_ary;
}

// this function saves photos to the database
public function save($room_id, $i){

    // first validate uploaded file
    $this->validatePhoto();

    if(empty($this->errors_on_upload)){ // insert data only if array with errors is empty

        $this->filename = time() . $this->name;

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . static::$db_table . ' (room_id, main, name, type, size, path) VALUES (:room_id, :main, :name, :type, :size, :path)';
        $db  = static::getDB();

        $stm = $db->prepare($sql);

        $i = ($i === 0) ? true : false;

        $stm->bindValue(':room_id', $room_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->bindValue(':main', $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->bindValue(':name', $this->filename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->bindValue(':type', $this->type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stm->bindValue(':size', $this->size, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stm->bindValue(':path', $this->pathToPicture(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stm->execute();

        $target_path = dirname(__DIR__, 3) . Config::DS . static::$upload_derictory . Config::DS . $this->filename;
        if(file_exists($target_path)){
            $this->errors_on_upload[] = 'This file already exists in this directory';
            return false;
        }

        if( !empty($this->tmp_name)){ // if tmp_name is empty, we just don't upload files

            if( ! move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name, $target_path)){
                $this->errors_on_upload[] = 'The folder probably doesnt have permissions';
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }

    }
    return false; // on failure
}



// this method validates pictures on upload
protected function validatePhoto(){

    $extension = $this->type;

    if( !empty($extension)){
        if($extension != 'image/jpeg' && $extension != 'image/png' && $extension != 'image/jpg'){
            $this->errors_on_upload[] = "Your file should be .jpeg, .jpg or .png";
        }
    }

    if($this->size > Config::MAX_FILE_SIZE){
        $this->errors_on_upload[] = "Your picture shouldn't be more than 10 Mb";
    }

    if($this->error != 0 && $this->error != 4) { //0 means no error, so if otherwise, display a respective message, 4 no files to upload, we allow that
        $this->errors_on_upload[] = $this->upload_errors_array[$this->error];
    }

}



protected function pathToPicture(){
    return static::$path . Config::DS . $this->filename;
}




public static function findAllPhotosToONeRoom($room_id, $main_photo_only){

    $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM photos WHERE room_id = :id'; // we need to pass only the main picture to all_rooms template
    $sql .= $main_photo_only ? ' AND main = 1' : '';    // get only main photo or all

    $db  = static::getDB();

    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);

    $stm->bindValue(':id', $room_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);



    if(($stm->execute())){


        if($main_photo_only){        // fetch all or only one row (for all_rooms page or for a particular room page)

            $pictures = $stm->fetch();

            return $pictures;

        } else {
            $pictures = $stm->fetchAll();

            return $pictures;
        }



    } else {
        // return a sample array with placeholder on failure instead of false to avoid further use 'false' as an array
        return false;
    }


}

// sets photo as a main by id and unsets prev main one
public static function setPictureAsMain($picture_id, $room_id){

    // check whether id's were supplied by AJAX request
    if($picture_id !== null && $room_id !== null){

        // first set old main photo main column to 0
        if(static::unsetMainPhoto($room_id)){

            // set chosen photo as main
            $sql = 'UPDATE ' . static::$db_table . ' SET main = 1 WHERE id = :picture_id';
            $db  = static::getDB();

            $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindValue(':picture_id', $picture_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

            return $stm->execute();

        }

    }

     return false;

}

// unsets main photo of a room
public static function unsetMainPhoto($room_id){

    $sql = 'UPDATE ' . static::$db_table . ' SET main = 0 WHERE room_id = :room_id AND main = 1';
    $db  = static::getDB();

    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':room_id', $room_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    return $stm->execute();
}


// this method adds photos to an existing room
public static function addPhotos($room_id, $pictures){

    // array for errors
    $errors_on_update = array();

    foreach ($pictures as $picture){

       if($picture->save($room_id, true)){

           $errors_on_update[] = true;

       }

    }

    return in_array(0, $errors_on_update, false) ? false : true;

}


// this method deletes images from upload folder
public static function unlinkImages($filename){
    return unlink(static::$path_to_unlink . $filename);
}



}`
```

Comment: Could you edit your code and add the rest of the class? (namespace and the whole shebang)

Comment: Do you know what the value is of `get_called_class()` at the time of `$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class());`
?

Comment: How do you call method `findById` in `C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\App\Controllers\Admin\Rooms.php` on line 188? `Core\Model::findById` or `static::findById` or `self::findById`?

Comment: I call `FindById` like this: `$photo = Photo::findById($id); ` due to Photo model extends `Core\Model` where this method is located. I'm not sure about precise value of `get_called_class`but the error remains even if I specify class manually like `$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\App\Models\Admin\Photo')` It only goes away if i comment out the line with setting of fetch mode, but it returns an array in this case which is not what I'd like to get. @Dymen1, @VladimirKovpak

Comment: Could you try using `static::class` instead of `get_called_class()`

Comment: Also do you use an autoloader or include the files manually?

Comment: And are you using the magic `__set` function?

Comment: @Dymen1, I tried to use `static::class` instead of  `get_called_class()` but that didn't help. I don't include all files manually but use composer's autoloader for that purpose. I have only two directories with my php classes and all other classes look to be loaded well. Also, when I use this `findById()` method  from other models it works fine. I don't use `__set()`magic method and it looks like I'm not getting hot to use it in this case

Comment: Does your Photos class have public properties or private with setters? (Could you add the Photo class to you question)

Comment: @Dymen1, just added my whole Photo class.. I have several protected properties in that class, but they are paths to uploaded files. The vast majority of properties however (like size or name) are created through it's `__constructor()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation:

```
public array PDOStatement::fetchAll (
    int $fetch_style,
    mixed $fetch_argument,
    array $ctor_args = array()
)
```

**ctor_args**

> Arguments of custom class constructor when the fetch_style parameter is PDO::FETCH_CLASS.

the same argument is available for **setFetchMode**

```
public bool PDOStatement::setFetchMode (
    int $PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    string $classname,
    array $ctorargs
)
```

I would implement this accordingly:

First add a property **$ctorArgs** to `\Core\Model` with a default value of `null`. Followed by replacing the current **setFetchMode** calls

```
if (!is_array($this->ctorArgs)) {
    throw new \Excpeption("\"ctorArgs\" must be of type array");
}
$stm->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class(), $this->ctorArgs);
```

And finally add a property **$ctorArgs** to `\App\Models\Admin\Photo` with a default value of `array("picture")`.

This will tell the code that your constructor is expecting the parameter **$picture**.

I would think about using a constant instead of a property, but that depends on how you decide to implement this.

Comment: It looks like this eventually got my code running. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Could you mark my answer if it answered your question?

Comment: I did, but according to the terms of stackoverflow my marks are not shown due to not sufficient reputation - it's only 9 while 15 is required (I'm a relative newbie here). I hope I will gain it soon and my mark will be shown. Thank you for your help one more time.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct response to the OP's specific issue, but `General error: could not call class constructor` could also mean that while the specified class constructor call was successful, the values from the database do not match the class-defined properties types.

For example, trying to use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` with the following class:

```php
class Something {
  public string $foo;
}
```

Would return the above error if the value of the `foo` column would happen to be null for any returned rows.

To find the real problem, one needs in look at the `PDOException`'s `getPrevious()`, which would contain a `TypeError` with the message `Cannot assign null to property Something::$foo of type string`, for the above example.